# Draw object to screen without being affected by rotation / zooming

Tags: xna, 2d, rotation, scale

I have a 2D game, with a camera that follows the main player. In the game the camera may also rotate the view around the player / zoom in or out on the player.

Let's say I want to add a mini-map to the bottom right of the screen. Is there any way that I can draw the mini-map on the screen so that it is not affected by the camera's zoom / rotation? Is there a way to draw directly to screen coordinates instead of the world coordinates?

Or do I have to perform a transform on the mini-map whenever the camera rotates or zooms.

Thank you for any help

Comment: More literally duplicate than most questions; same poster, same topic, same problem, same post date.